# Could Satisfy be used intransitively?

Tags: verbs

> My life satisfies so much that even though I have not as much fortune as rich people, I am not envious of them at all.(I made this sentence myself)

The meaning I want to convey is the fact that the state of my life, as it is, consists of satisfaction, so I think 'satisfy' can be an intransitive verb, even though no dictionary defines the verb can be used in the way.

Comment: When you use 'satisfies' in such a way, you need to specify a target of the satisfaction - either 'My life satisfies me so much that...' or 'My life satisfies my family so much that...'.

Comment: The "me" is implied, even if you don't say it.

Answer (score 1):

"Satisfy" can be used intransitively, but this example seems awkward to me.

It's not uncommon to say, "This is a meal that really satisfies!" Decades ago Chesterfield cigarettes used the slogan, "Nothing satisfies like the big clean taste of Chesterfield".

But for reasons I can't put my finger on, your example just sounds awkward to me. Also, you shouldn't say "I have not as much fortune", but "I do not have as much fortune". Or better, leave out "much", and just say "I don't have a fortune". I would say, "My life is so satisfying that even though I don't have a fortune like rich people, I am not envious of them."

Comment: "I have not as much fortune", but isn't it grammatically correct, even though it is awkward?

Comment: You can say "not so much of a fortune" or "not so great a fortune" but you will sound like you're trying to write like Jane Austen.

Comment: "Fortune" is not considered countable in modern usage -- it is more like a liquid. You can't have "more fortune" or "less fortune". You can have "a bigger fortune" or "a smaller fortune".